# Files to Base64 conversion using RNFS

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Im trying to convert a file to base 64. for that im using [react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker) and [RNFS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs).

Problem: When files is picked thru
[react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker) it gives me success and the path is temporary cache path. but when i try to convert it to base64 using [RNFS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) it gives me that error.
it will pick file from iCloud but not which is showed as "On My iPhone" in file manager i think issue is its not pick images from local storage of iPhone.

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A78E7E14-DBAC/tmp/com.xyz-Inbox/Scanned%20Document.pdf'

here's my code:

```
const response = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
copyTo: "documentDirectory" });
var data = await RNFS.readFile(response.uri, 'base64');
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post your code ? It might be that you try to convert the file before its saved.

Comment: @MichaelBahl now check

Comment: Did you try using RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath + ‘/Inbox/filename.xyz‘

Comment: yes i tried like this                  var url = responseuri;
            const split = url.split('/')
            
            const name = split.pop()
            const inbox = split.pop()
            const realPath = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}${inbox}/${name}`

Comment: /tmp/com.xyz-Inbox/Scanned -> /tmp/com.xyz/Inbox/Scanned

Comment: @MichaelBahl nope i tried this but its not working also